# How can I download flutter web app on pressing a button?

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

This question is a bit theoretical as i don't have a direction to proceed. We know that flutter web app can be downloaded on any platform by clicking on the download button present next to url tab in chrome and in mobile from the menu button. This download is turned as .apk in android and can be used without opening from chrome. So, i wanted to know how can i perform this download task by pressing a button in my flutter app.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is quite simple. Firstly prepare the `.apk` file somewhere, say, `https://example.com/myapp.apk`. Then, when the button is pressed, simply navigate to that url, and it is done.

Comment: But how can i make the apk of flutter web app(PWA) and similar extensions for other platforms? I know through html we can show popup to download the PWA but how to do so in flutter?

Comment: flutter can package your app into an apk file as well as an ipa file.e.g. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: why you want to download pwa, when you can download apk/ipa files - which is a **real** app!

Comment: indeed, if you want to install pwa, here it goes: https://www.amitmerchant.com/adding-custom-install-button-in-progressive-web-apps/